# Download a file after processing ajax request

Tags: java, spring, excel, model-view-controller

I'm creating a workbook object(excel object "org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook") on an ajax request.

How can I send this file from servlet to browser and let the browser pops up a download box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling I get to know its difficult to do with an ajax request.

So I decided to go with hidden form. 
In javascript I created a hidden form and submitted the form So I am getting the excel download pop-up.

my javascript is given below.

```
    var form = document.createElement("form"); //created dummy form for submitting.
    var element1 = document.createElement("input"); 
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = "/my/servlet/path";

    element1.value=values; //its a json string I need to pass to server.
    element1.name="data";
    element1.type = 'hidden'
    form.appendChild(element1);

    document.body.appendChild(form);

    form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set Content-Type to `application/x-msdownload` and  Header to `Content-Disposition`

For example:

```
    String fileName = URLDecoder.decode("MyBook.xlsx", "ISO8859_1");//Change if required
    response.setContentType("application/x-msdownload");            
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);
//And just write output stream here
```

Since you have changed the response headers so a Browser will automatically display a popup message to download the file.

Comment: I dont have the file location.. its dynamically generated. and saved nowhere.

Comment: If you don't have a physical file then just write your dynamically generated content to out.write and specify any value to fileName with valid extension. e.g. String fileName="MyContent.xlsx"

Comment: what is to be done in jsp..? Currently I am creating a modelAndView and posting it..

Comment: Your question says that you are making a servlet call therfor you should push your file from there only.

Comment: }).done(function(data) { alert(data);}
Currently I am just alerting the data recived back. what  should be the changes for the download to start.'

Comment: Just read all of my responses again and try to understand. I have already answered howto handle this.